# Why can't I read this file on a remote AWS server in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services

I launched a couple servers in AWS and I want to read the contents of the a file using Powershell.

On server 1 I create a file called `App_configuration.txt` and placed in the root of `c:\`.

The file has just 2 lines in it:

```
<Path>C:\GoodToGo</Path>
<Path>C:\GoodToGo2</Path>
```

I'm trying to access the file with this command using the remote IP of the server. The `xx.xxx.xx.xxx` is supposed to be the remote IP:

```
Get-Content -Path "\\xx.xxx.xx.xxx\c$\App_configuration.txt"
Get-Content : Cannot find path '\\xx.xxx.xx.xxx\c$\App_configuration.txt' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Content -Path "\\xx.xxx.xx.xxx\c$\App_configuration.txt"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\\xx.xxx.xx.xxx\c$\App_configuration.txt:String) [Get-Content], ItemNot
   FoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

I can RDP into the remote server and list the file:

```
PS C:\> ls C:\App_configuration.txt


    Directory: C:\


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----         3/2/2021   4:12 PM             51 App_configuration.txt
```

I am not the same user on my local machine as the one that can log into the remote machine. The server I am trying to access is in AWS, and I am trying to access it from my local machine.

I have the powershell port `5985` open on the AWS security group (firewall) and I can connect to it remotely using telnet.

Why can't I read this remote file with this powershell line? I think the issue might be network related.

Comment: Have you tried to mount `\\xx.xxx.xx.xxx\c$\` as a network drive?  If you are able to do that then the problem is a syntax problem.

Comment: @TimDunphy If you do go to ``\\xx.xxx.xx.xxx\c$\`` on the machine you run the PowerShell from, are you able to open that file and read from it that way? You will need that level of access or to enter a credential to authenticate to that resource and then run the command. You can also consider running invoke-command and running the process that way from the local file system path and not the hidden C$ admin share. I can think of a few ways to tackle this process depending on your configuration and authentication hop needs, and so forth.

Comment: @DrinkMorePimpJuiceIT No, I am trying to open a file in AWS from my local machine. If I try to do that I get the error I show in the OP. I can log into the AWS machine and access the file from both the `c$` share and the local file system: `c:\` no problem.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: The AWS system is running on Windows Server 2019 or what OS? You have to allow file and print sharing through the Windows FW for `\\ipaddress\c$` to be accessible. Furthermore, the credential you authenticate against the `\\ipaddress\c$` "remotely" but be a local administrator on the AWS server. With those two things, you should be able to access the Windows C$ hidden admin share no problem remotely. Otherwise, you'd need to authenticate and/or open the protocol/ports to be allowable inbound for the network zone from the OS perspective. Using `invoke-command` may be better than C$ for you tho

Comment: @DrinkMorePimpJuiceIT yes, the remote server is running Windows Server 2019. Also the powershell port `5985` is open on the firewall (security group) and I can telnet to it from my local machine. I think it may be an authentication problem, because I am not the same user on my local machine as I am on the remote that can access the file. How do I authenticate using the `Get-Content` command?

Comment: SMB or file sharing uses different ports - typically at least 135. You can provide a credential to `New-PSDrive` to access file shares as another user. I would recommend using `Invoke-Command` instead of opening up file sharing though in most cases.

Comment: @DrinkMorePimpJuiceIT busy day, I'll try to get to this later today or tomorrow. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Invoke-Command](https://ss64.com/ps/invoke-command.html) and run `Get-Content` command from within it since you have port `5985` open.

Otherwise allow [SMB: File and print sharing](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/best-practices-analyzer/smb-open-file-sharing-ports) or applicable TCP ports through your Windows Firewall.

#### PowerShell Remote Invoke-Command

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName <IP Address> -ScriptBlock { Process {
    Get-Content -Path "C:\App_configuration.txt"
    }
};
```

#### PowerShell Remote Invoke-Command (with credential)

```
$cred = Get-Credential "domain\administrator" 

Invoke-Command -ComputerName <IP Address> -ScriptBlock { Process {
    Get-Content -Path "C:\App_configuration.txt"
    }
} -AsJob -Credential $cred;
```

---

### Supporting Resources

- [Enable-PSRemoting](https://ss64.com/ps/enable-psremoting.html)
- [Invoke-Command](https://ss64.com/ps/invoke-command.html)

  > `-ScriptBlock scriptblock`
  >
  > The commands to run.
  >
  > Enclose the commands in curly braces `{ }` to
  > create a script block. This parameter is required.
- [Internet firewalls can prevent browsing and file sharing](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/networking/internet-firewalls-prevent-browsing-file-sharing#:%7E:text=Microsoft%20file%20sharing%20SMB%3A%20User,445%20(TCP%20and%20UPD).)

  > Microsoft file sharing SMB: User Datagram Protocol (UDP) ports from
  > 135 through 139 and Transmission Control Protocol (TCP) ports from 135
  > through 139. Direct-hosted SMB traffic without a network basic
  > input/output system (NetBIOS): port 445 (TCP and UPD).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120667/discussion-on-answer-by-drink-more-pimp-juice-it-why-cant-i-read-this-file-on-a).